Sharepoint Lists - JSON formats to display user email and other attributes
I have a list with a Person column named 'Resource'.  I also made an 'Email' text column.
Email is formatted:
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "[$Resource.email]"
}

Which works great - I get the persons email displayed.
I then tried [$Resource.title] assuming that I would get "Project Manager" etc. except I get "Bob Smith" etc.
I am not the admin but I do have access to the SP admin.  I have seen the SP user list.  There is a 'title' and 'department' with data.
Am I missing something basic here - can I not access the users full information and just email?
Is there a list somewhere that details these hidden user field that are available?

JSON formatting supports id, title, email, sip, picture, department and jobTitle properties.
To get department property, please use following JSON codes.
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "[$Resource.department]"
}

